# python raising an exception inside if statement

Tags: python, exception

I want to test if there is certain string inside the object name and return the path name according to it. If there is nothing found I want to throw an error.
Here is my code:

```
def object_path(object_name):
    try:
        if object_type(object_name) in ['JX', 'JW', 'MT', 'WF']:
            obj_path = 'task'
        elif object_type(object_name) in ['TT', 'MT', 'FT']:
            obj_path = 'trigger'
        elif object_type(object_name) == 'VR':
            obj_path = 'virtual'
        else:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError as err:
        print('The name of  object {} is 
           incorrect'.format(object_name))
    return obj_path

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = object_path('L8H_gh_hgkjjkh')
    print (x)
```

It does not seem right, this is what it throws me back:

```
The name of UAC object L8H_gh_hgkjjkh is incorrect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uac_api_lib.py", line 29, in <module>
    x = object_path('L8H_gh_hgkjjkh')
  File "uac_api_lib.py", line 24, in object_path
    return obj_path
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'obj_path' referenced before assignment
```

Would you help me fix it?

Comment: You're throwing a `ValueError` but then you're catching it in the same function. After the exception is caught, you hit the return statement and cause another error.

Comment: before `try` write `obj_path = ''`

Comment: @khelwood can you help me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your function to throw a `ValueError`, then don't catch it in the function.

```
def object_path(object_name):
    if object_type(object_name) in ['JX', 'JW', 'MT', 'WF']:
        obj_path = 'task'
    elif object_type(object_name) in ['TT', 'MT', 'FT']:
        obj_path = 'trigger'
    elif object_type(object_name) == 'VR':
        obj_path = 'virtual'
    else:
        raise ValueError('The name of object {} is incorrect'.format(object_name))
    return obj_path
```

Also, you could simplify it like this:

```
def object_path(object_name):
    otype = object_type(object_name)
    if otype in {'JX', 'JW', 'MT', 'WF'}:
        return 'task'
    if otype in {'TT', 'MT', 'FT'}:
        return 'trigger'
    if otype == 'VR':
        return 'virtual'
    raise ValueError('The name of object {} is incorrect'.format(object_name))
```

but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The "referenced before assignment" error is there cause obj_path exists only inside your try/except block. Just define it before that.

```
def object_path(object_name):
    obj_path = ""
    try:
        if object_type(object_name) in ['JX', 'JW', 'MT', 'WF']:
            obj_path = 'task'
        elif object_type(object_name) in ['TT', 'MT', 'FT']:
            obj_path = 'trigger'
        elif object_type(object_name) == 'VR':
            obj_path = 'virtual'
        else:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError as err:
        print('The name of  object {} is 
           incorrect'.format(object_name))
    return obj_path
```